# Objective-C > Landscape view does not return after taking or choosing a photo

Tags: objective-c, layout, landscape, portrait

I have an app (LandScape mode only) I'm working on in which there are several areas where the user will either take a photo or choose an existing photo.  Upon coming back from the camera or Photo library the view will not go back to landscape mode automatically (you have to tilt the iPad around) otherwise you can see a large section of white.  I've tried using the following but it doesn't have any effect:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
                         (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
                 interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

The picture is landscape but the layout of the app is still in portrait from being pushed to the camera and back.

[image: Stuck in portrait]

Does anyone have ideas on how to get it to correctly auto-rotate back?